# iPhone app that allows simultaneous playing of music to multiple devices

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, music

The idea is to use each iPhone as a speaker for one track of music.

Picture it: you are in the park, having a picnic and you would like your music to be played louder. Why not sync all the iPhones to play the same song at the same time?

Does such an app exist?

Comment: iOS does not natively support AirPlay to multiple speakers, so this would have to be a third-party app. The question is really just whether such an app exists. (I know this doesn't answer the question, and I'm fairly sure *you* know this already — I'm just saying this for the sake of clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/), to stream music from your Mac using [Airfoil for Mac](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) to any iOS device with the [Airfoil Speakers Touch](http://itunes.apple.com/app/airfoil-speakers-touch/id311357351?mt=8) app (free). It is as simple as turning on a speaker system, one button and you have the streaming audio from your Mac on your iOS device. I would highly recommend this!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think you are missing the point a bit here. It should be from iPhone to iPhone, not Mac to iPhone. The idea being mobility. I don't want to have to bring my laptop to the park :)

Comment: @EricBrotto Ah. I see. Sorry about that!! Can you clarify your question a bit to add that?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Seedio](http://itunes.apple.com/app/seedio/id546283234?l=fr&mt=8) and [Seedio Free](http://itunes.apple.com/app/seedio-free/id550878366?l=fr&mt=8) do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

back in 2013, I was one of the co-founders of Audibly, wireless synchronized surround sound for iOS. I was kind of late to see this while googling something completely unrelated to the question, but I was like Hey, I built what he needs! This'll take a sec.

http://audibly.co

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audibly-make-your-music-heard./id882170258?ls=1&mt=8

https://techcrunch.com/2014/06/11/audibly-turns-multiple-ios-devices-into-a-wireless-surround-sound-system/

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why jail breaking is so amazing :) , jailbreak it and install airplayspeaker and there u go :) or there zillions of apps that do that to though I don't remember there names but airplayspeaker built in so why not take advantage of that

Comment: We ask that people do the research and link to software that does X - especially if there are tens of them as that adds value. Thanks for the answer and endorsement on jailbreaking - would you edit this to turn it into something more useful with details others can use?

Answer (score 0):

[AmpMe on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ampme-a-portable-social-party-music-speaker/id986905979?mt=8) is built exactly for that reason. Check their [website](http://www.ampme.com/).

From what i can see, it supports both Android & iOS. Enjoy the party & picnic.

For Android users, here is the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amp.android) link.