# Stream the same song on two devices with apple music?

Tags: music, bluetooth, appletv, apple-music

My goal is to find a way to play the same music (same song with control from one device, ideally) on a soundbar (either via bluetooth or an apple TV) and another bluetooth speaker.

We have an Apple Music family plan.

We have an iPad, iPhone, and Macbook Air. We also have an apple TV (4th gen) connected to a samsung soundbar (also had bluetooth as an option) as well as a bluetooth speaker.

I was thinking there would hopefully be a way to play the same thing on the apple tv and the ipad so that the apple tv would play through the soundbar and the ipad would play through the bluetooth speaker.

It seems like this is a nice feature for them to have, but wouldn't surprise me if they don't have it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of at least [one of](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34730/12285) [these](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51798/12285) [questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22943/playing-the-same-music-on-multiple-computers).

Comment: (Granted, Apple Music is a new variable not included in those, but as of now it doesn't change the answer at all.)